# websocket & node.js wont connect on windows azure

Tags: node.js, iis, azure, websocket

I tried to run ws on node.js in windows azure website. the connection works on my localhost but not on the azure... I enabled the web socket in the portal.

the connection listed as padding and then fail.

there is the code

server.js

```
console.log("ws is on");

var ipaddress = 'localhost';
var port = 8080;

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({host:ipaddress, port:port});

wss.broadcast = function(data) {
  for (var i in this.clients)
    this.clients[i].send(data);
};

// use like this:
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    console.log("dor");
  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    wss.broadcast(message);
  });
});
console.log('Listening to ' + ipaddress + ':' + port + ' ...');
```

web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
          <match url="ws"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

clint

```
var url = "testserverside.azurewebsites.net";

            var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + url + ":8080","sip");

            console.log(socket.readyState);
            socket.onopen = function()
            {
                alert("Socket has been opened!");
            }

            socket.onerror = function(err)
            {
                alert(err)
            };
```

#### Solved

The problem was the port i used. In azure you should use only port 80.

Comment: I've been struggling with the same exact problem.

Comment: i think the problam is that they block port 8080 for websites